# How to use IServiceProvider in IServiceBehavior, IOperationBehaviour custom interfaces in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a custom .NET framework library which is used for different purposes like logging, security etc in my `WCF` application. Currently we make use of [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) in both cases, for the library and the `WCF` application as well. But recently we decided to move out Autofac and use [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/) because consumers might want to use a different DI package. Changing stuff was easy until I started making changes to some attributes we use throughout application.

For example we have an attribute which looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class SecurityBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior, IOperationBehavior
{
    private readonly ISecurityManager _securityManager;

    public SecurityBehaviorAttribute()
    {
        _securityManager = AutofacHostFactory.Container.Resolve<ISecurityManager>();
    }

    //Implemented methods
}
```

Since we don't have `AutofacHostFactory.Container` in place anymore we need another way of getting these services but I am not sure if there is a way how to do this in `WCF` ?

While searching I found some info to create a custom `IInstanceProvider` which might help but still I am not sure how does it work because I did not find any example integrating it with abstraction package. Since in my top application we use [Autofac.Integration.Wcf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Wcf/) I think behind the scene this package creates a custom `IInstanceProvider` for internal needs, if so, how can I get this interface injected to my attribute and how to use it (*this way the consumer would be responsible for creating a custom `IInstanceProvider` and I will just use it in my package*)?

Another ugly solution would be to create a singleton instance of `IServiceProvider` and make use of it(*not sure if it works well anyway*)

To wrap it up:

1. Is there a good/straightforward way how to resolve services in `WCF` attributes (*like the one above*) using only [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/) ?
2. If **1)** is not possible. Is there a way how to get `IInstanceProvider` which is created by top application(*from consumer of package in this case*) and use it here in the attribute ?
3. Is creating a static object of `IserviceProvider` the only solution or there are other good ways without big changes ?

Comment: Source code for [Autofac.Integration.Wcf](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Wcf/tree/develop/src/Autofac.Integration.Wcf). You could inspect it to see if your assumption is correct.

Comment: But there is no getting around the service locator pattern in those attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying so many ways I could not make anything else work except storing the `IServiceProvider` into a static property and reusing it.